# How to add new utterance to LUIS intent?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, microsoft-skype-bot

Please help me in LUIS training. I want to add new utterances to intent using LUIS API. But I can't find any examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try the [Add Label operation](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/56f8a55119845511c81de461) from the [LUIS Programatic API](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/5739a8c71984550500affdfa).