# Get all labels of an intent through LUIS Programmatic API

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to get all the added utterances of a specific intent. Saw there is a method to review all labels against all intents, another one to add a label against an intent as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389065/how-to-add-new-utterance-to-luis-intent). But could not find a method to get utterances of a single intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem that they gave us an endpoint with filtering possibilities.

Although not optimal we can still do that manually:

1. Call the endpoint in your case [this one.](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/56f8a55119845511c81de463)
2. Create classes from the retrieved json (Rename the top level classes)
   [image]
3. Deserialize the json and filter other objects.

And the code ;)

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{sub_key}");

        var uri = "your url" ;
        var json= await (await client.GetAsync(uri)).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var filterValue = "Zabun";
        Utterance[] filteredUtterances = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Utterance[]>(json)
            .Where(v => v.IntentsResults.Name.Equals(filterValue)).ToArray();
```